# How to silently install Visual Assist X in Visual Studio 2012 with licence

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-assist

If possible, we'd like the option of installing Visual Assist X (latest version) on PC with Visual Studio 2012 silently with the licence key already inserted.

Do you know if this is possible? I don't think Visual Studio 2010 and later supports command modifiers but maybe we could put the licence in the registry somewhere?

Comment: Well, this is a question that their support desk should answer very easily. Have you asked them?

Comment: Yes I asked them but didn't get a reply yet.

Comment: https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W281